# Spectral clustering of affinity matrix

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, cluster-analysis, eigenvector

I am trying to perform spectral clustering.

I have eigenvectors of a symmetric affinity matrix and I have to find [image: formula] (taken from a paper), where x'Mx is inter-cluster score.

1. Is x'Mx the same as the cluster vector and therefore argmax would mean a principal vector of eigenvectors (i.e. eigenvector with the highest eigenvalue)?
2. If so, the should x* be calculated for every cluster? (Because how can one vector describe all the clusters..)

---

In code (using OpenCV library)

```
    //a symmetric affinity matrix calculated prior
    CvScalar scal;
    CvMat* evec  = cvCreateMat(src->height,src->height,CV_32FC1); //eigenvectors
    CvMat* eval  = cvCreateMat(1,src->height,CV_32FC1);  //eigenvalues (1xN)
    cvZero(evec);
    cvZero(eval);
    cvEigenVV(&mat, evec, eval, 1);

    //result is eval->cols == mat.cols and eval->rows == mat.rows
    for( int j = 0; j < eval->cols; j++ )
    {
        /*access the obtained eigenvalues*/
        scal = cvGet2D( eval, 0, j );
        printf( "\n%f\n", scal.val[0]);

        for(int i=0;i < evec->rows;i++){   
            printf(" vector: %d: %f ", j, cvmGet(evec,j,i)); //Fetching each component of Eigenvector i    
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible answer ([explained in paper "Efficient Feature Tracking for Scene Recognition using Angular and
Scale Constraints"](http://koasas.kaist.ac.kr/bitstream/10203/20440/1/Efficient%20Feature%20Tracking%20for%20Scene%20Recognition%20using%20Angular%20and%20Scale%20Constraints.pdf))

[image]
[image]

So, that means that

1) x* = eigenvector that has largest eigenvalue

2) principal eigenvector can describe different clusters. If one will plot values of a principal eigenvector, variations in the graph will indicate different clusters of the data